# The 'Name' and 'Src' attributes are mutually exclusive in aspx page without code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a webform (default.aspx) page without code behind in my website. Here i am using a dll reference to call method from it. Below are the Code details what i have done.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data;"%>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient;"%>
    <%@ Assembly name="ClassLibrary"  Src="~/Bin/ClassLibrary.dll"%>

    <script language="c#" runat="server">
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClassLibrary.Class1 obj = new ClassLibrary.Class1();
        Response.Write(obj.Test());
    }
    </script>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
    </div>
    </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

When I am starting executing my website it gives an error [The 'Name' and 'Src' attributes are mutually exclusive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzJvI.png)

Answer (score 0):

This means you can have one or the other. IE, `<%@ Assembly name="ClassLibrary" %>` or `<%@ Assembly Src="~/Bin/ClassLibrary.dll"%>`

Basically, 'Name' is going to tell it to go look for an assembly in the GAC and private probing path for a matching assembly, while 'Src' tells it the Assembly you want to load is 'right here at this path'.